# How to get the value from Text Editor in React Js? [Snippet attached]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, text-editor, draftjs

I am making a simple app that makes a JSON form and I have already included the basic details and employment details as two sections.

Basic details section has two inputs such as First Name and Last Name.

Now I am given the requirement to implement the Profile Summary control that should be a text editor and the values entered needs to be stored in JSON format.

Please look at the JSON format in the given codesandbox link.

File that forms JSON: https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-css-only-carousel-forked-8grpo?file=/components/form_context.js

```
{
    basicDetails: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      profileSummary: "" --------> This is where I need to fetch the text editor entered values
    },
    companyDetails: [
      {
        companyName: "",
        designation: "",
        startDate: ""
      }
    ]
  }
```

Text Editor file: https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-css-only-carousel-forked-8grpo?file=/components/text_editor.js

**Requirement:**

The requirement is that the text editor value needs to be stored inside the JSON format.

Eg: If the the text is made `bold` or `bullet list` in the editor then the value of the key `profileSummary` needs to be added with respective tags.

I am trying to achieve the text editor field value like here: https://www.ippy.io/

As I am trying to build a resume like structure, Unable to get the point of how should I need to make the text editor value into JSON key `profileSummary`.

**Complete working example:**

> **https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-css-only-carousel-forked-8grpo**

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime `editorState` change, you need to get its plain HTML equivalent and pass that to your `BasicDetails` component.

```js
onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
  // console.log(editorState);

  this.setState({ editorState }, () => {
    // state updated

    // convert editorState to plain HTML
    const contentRaw = convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent());
    const contentHTML = draftToHtml(contentRaw);

    const fakeEvent = {
      target: {
        name: this.props.name,
        value: contentHTML
      }
    };

    // call onChange function from Parent passing the
    // fakeEvent object
    this.props.onChange(fakeEvent);
  });
};
```

On your `BasicDetails` you pass `onChange` and `name` prop to `EditorContainer` component.

```js
...

<EditorContainer
  name="profileSummary"
  onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(event)}
/>
```

Unfortunately, converting DraftJS Editor content to plain HTML is not built-in on `draft-js` library, in fact they only support the following functions for data convertions

- [`convertFromRaw`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion/#convertfromraw)
- [`convertToRaw`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion/#converttoraw)
- [`convertFromHTML`](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion/#convertfromhtml)

So you are required to use another library, in my code above I'm using [`draftjs-to-html`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/draftjs-to-html) - the same person who created [`react-draft-wysiwyg`](https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/).

**Edit** We can avoid setting the `profileSummary` with empty `p` tag by checking if `editorState` has some text.

```js
this.setState({ editorState }, () => {
  const currentContent = editorState.getCurrentContent();
  const contentRaw = convertToRaw(currentContent);
  const value = currentContent.hasText() ? draftToHtml(contentRaw) : "";

  const fakeEvent = {
    target: {
      name: this.props.name,
      value
    }
  };

  this.props.onChange(fakeEvent);
});
```

[image: Edit next.js + css-only carousel (forked)]

Comment: Bro, Could you help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63717261/how-to-make-step-wizard-form-in-reactjs ?

Answer (score 0):

You need write a funtion  `hangleEditorChange` in  BasicDetails.

Then,

````js
# basic_detail.js
  ...
 <div className="">
        <label htmlFor="lastName">Profile Summary</label>
        <EditorContainer  onChnage ={hangleEditorChange}/>
   </div>
...


```js
# text_editor.js

  onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({
      editorState
    });
   this.props.onChange(editorState)
  };
````